# Why do I continue to get this error despite the fact that I added the link_to "Sign In"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Doing some BDD for my Ruby on Rails project and Guard continues to give me this message:

```
Users sign-in with valid credentials Failure/Error: click_link "Sign in" Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find link "Sign in"
```

In spite of the fact that I have added "Sign In", take a look at the code here:

This is partial code from my app/views/devise/layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top"     role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button"     class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-    target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="icon-bar">    </span>
                    <span class="icon-bar">    </span>
                    <span class="icon-bar">    </span>
                </button>
                <%= link_to "Blog App",     root_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapsecollapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><%= link_to "Authors", "#" %></li>
                    <% if user_signed_in? %>
                        <div class="navbar-right">
                            <p class="navbar-text">Signed in as <%= "#{current_user.email}" %></p>
                        </div>
                    <% end %>
                    <li><%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "Sign In", new_user_session_path %></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: I'm not a Capybara expert but perhaps it is looking for "Sign in" (click_link "Sign in") and in your code you have "Sign In"

Comment: @Mat, you are absolutely correct. I just looked at my signing_users_in_spec.rb. Go ahead and mark your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Capybara is looking for "Sign in" (click_link "Sign in") and in your code you have "Sign In".